# Two Assignments On One Line

Tags: objective-c

I understand that such code is used in Objective C.

```
_conversation.lastMessageSentDate = message.sentDate = [NSDate date];
```

Am I right in assuming that this code sets both `conversation.lastMessageSentDate` and `message.sentDate` to `NSDate date`?

Or am I misunderstanding this line of code?

Do other languages have such formatting?
I have programmed in Python and Java and never saw any code like this.

Thanks.

Comment: If I saw that line of code, I would rewrite it into two distinct assignments just to avoid my brain compiling that line of code as `_conversation.lastMessageSentDate = message.sentDate == [NSDate date];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not two declarations, these are two assignment statements. You are absolutely correct about the way it works, too.

The reason that it works is that an assignment expression is a valid expression that produces a value. The rightmost assignment gets evaluated first

```
message.sentDate = [NSDate date]
```

and then the second assignment:

```
_conversation.lastMessageSentDate = /*the result of the first assignment*/
```

Note that it's the order of evaluation, not the order of actual assignments: these may happen in any order, because the order of side effects is not specified in the absence of sequence points.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I was trying to get the word in my head, I just forgot what it was called lol. Oh interesting, I didn't know that evaluation starts from the right. You learn something new everyday! Thanks

Comment: @GangstaGraham Evaluation goes right-to-left only for some operators. Here is a [link to the table that shows which operators go left-to-right and which ones are done right-to-left](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Implicit in this explanation is that both variables point to the same object, rather than the two separate objects you'd get if each assignment was on its own line. You need to be sure that you really do want just the one object if that object is mutable, @GangstaGraham.

Comment: Thanks @josh-caswell  that was a nice snippet of info! In this example, yes I would not mind this happening. But I will careful before doing this in the future. Also, thanks once again, because I would have left this question with the wrong impression, if it had not been for that comment. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple assignments are common in many languages, people just use them less frequently than single assignments.

Ruby does some interesting things with multiple assignments, such as:

```
name, address1, address2, city, step = record.split(',')  # split a CSV record into multiple fields
```

Comment: Oh ok, I've seen that formatting (with the commas) before, just I've never seen with two equals before I guess. Thanks!

Comment: This snippet is misleading in the context of C; only the last variable would have anything assigned to it.

Comment: That's true, but he asked if other languages had such a convention, so it's answers the question (and it is marked as Ruby).